# How to create axis2 login handler

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, handler

I'm studying web services with Axis2, I have to create a handler that checks whether a user can access to a service. I did this, but how can I return an error message to the client?
For now I'm using the AxisFaultException, is this a good practice?
Is possible to give another chance to the user? maybe using InvocationResponse.Suspend..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build authentication (username/password) within the application layer, the answer to your question is yes, a soap exception is good practice.

When the user (the client) tries to access your service, it probably uses libraries/applications to communicate with your service, and catching soap exceptions should not be a problem.

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with additional attempts, but they should come in new requests, not within the same request.